# Adding multiple hotkeys to an element with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm currently using Angular UI to add a hotkey to an element, but it doesn't seem to support multiple hotkeys. What would be the best way to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Not using Angular-UI, but you maybe you could have a look to the [angular-hotkeys](https://github.com/drahak/angular-hotkeys) directive, it allow you to bind one or more keys to an event function.

*Example*

```
<div hotkey="{ 'A': functionA, 'B': functionB }"></div>

$scope.functionA = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('A key pressed.');
}

$scope.functionB = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('B key pressed.');
}
```